# On hiragana, romaji and pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana, rōmaji

I have heard a Japanese teacher explain how long vowels should be pronounced and how they should be written when using hiragana. That's what I saw on the whiteboard:

> がっこう - gakko**o**, (*not* gakko**u**)

Is it correct? I understand that the sound is pretty much the same. But if it's gakko**o**, then the hiragana version should be *がっこお*, which is not OK.

Comment: Of course there are always the exceptions, the first of which that comes to mind is 大き (おおき).  The others that I know have slipped my mind at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know there are several romanization systems, each of which treats long vowels fairly differently? [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese) is a good starter.

**がっこう**

- Nihon-shiki/Kunrei-shiki system: **gakkô**
- Hepburn system: **gakkō** (although there are [many variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization#Variations))
- Passport-shiki system: **gakko**
- [JSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSL_romanization): **gakkoo**
- [Wāpuro style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C4%81puro_r%C5%8Dmaji): **gakkou**

If your teacher is using JSL, "gakkoo" is the correct Romanized spelling. Nevertheless, the only correct spelling in hiragana is がっこう.

Comment: A long "o" sound is typically written as おお only at the start of a word (e.g. おおきい), and as おう elsewhere, such as in がっこう. Just to make things more confusing, in katakana all long vowels tend to be marked with a dash, e.g. オーストラリア (o-sutoraria for Australia) or カード (ka-do for card).

Comment: Then there are cases like Inoue which are read Ino-ue and not inoo-e

Comment: @ConMan I think おお is only for kun'yomi like 大, whereas おう is for on'yomi like 王様(ousama), 桜蘭(ouran), 凹凸(outotsu), 黄金(oukin), 欧米(oubei), and more.